# Como usar um simulador de iOS em um ambiente Windows 10 para um projeto Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin-forms

O que eu preciso instalar para publicar um projeto Xamarin.Forms.iOS em um simulador de iOS?

Estou usando uma maquina com:
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2015

Sempre que eu tento rodar algum projeto de Xamarin.Forms.iOS aparece uma mensagem de: No remotely accessible Macs were detected on your network. For more information, click Where's my Mac?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfrQa.jpg]

Comment: Você precisará de um Mac mesmo. Você até encontrar algumas maneiras de virtualizar o Mac no Windows, mas essa prática é ilegal.

Comment: Penso que seja necessário rodar o simulador em uma máquina com OSX ou no mínimo, como o erro informa, uma máquina com OSX (Macs) na rede pra executar remotamente.

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar a compilação e simulação de uma aplicação iOS no Windows, infelizmente, você necessitará de um computador da Apple conectado na rede, pois, a Apple exige que as suas aplicações somente sejam compiladas em seus dispositivos(computadores), mais uma evidencia que o Xamarin é realmente nativo ;).

Como bem sabemos um computador da Apple não é nada barato, porém, existem soluções legais que podem te auxiliar neste sentido, que é o aluguel de maquinas Apple, com elas será possível conectar nelas e realizar a compilação e simulação.

Segue alguns links que oferecem este serviço:

http://www.macincloud.com/

https://xcloud.me/

Comment: Além disso é necessário ter a versão Enterprise do Visual Studio!